# expressjs conditional view render path

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug, overriding

I'm writing an app using expressjs. I have my views in, commonly, ***/views*** folder. They cover 90% of my customers' needs, but sometimes I have to override one or another of those view to add custom-tailored features. I really wonder I can build a folder structure like:

```
*{ ...other expressjs files and folders...}*
/views
    view1.jade
    view2.jade
    view2.jade
/customerA
    view2.jade
/customerB
    view3.jade
```

What I'd like is to override the behaviour of expressjs' ***response.render()*** function to apply the following algorithm:

```
1. a customer requests a view
2. if /{customer_folder}/{view_name}.jade exists, than
       render /{customer_folder}/{view_name}.jade
   else
       render /views/{view_name}.jade
```

Thus, for ***customerA***, ***response.render('view1')*** will refer to ***/views/view1.jade*** while ***response.render('view2')*** will refer to ***/customerA/view2.jade*** 
(those who use appcelerator's titanium may sound it familiar)

I'd like an elegant way to implement this behavior *without* the hassle of modify expressjs' core functionality, and thus possibly get treated at upgrading my framework. I guess it's a common problem but I can't find any article on the web.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can hook `http.ServerResponse.render`.

Here's some code from the top of my head, to be used as middleware:

```
var backup = res.render
res.render = function() {
    //Do your thing with the arguments array, maybe use environment variables
    backup.apply(res, arguments) //Function.prototype.apply calls a function in context of argument 1, with argument 2 being the argument array for the actual call
}
```

Comment: so you're saying i can get to the point by creating a custom middleware and attaching it to my server instance?

Comment: Yes, it needs to be at the top of the load order though, before anyone would call `res.render`

Comment: ok, i think your answer is the hint i was looking for - now i can find proper examples on the web. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would create a custom `View` class:

```
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();
var View    = app.get('view');

var MyView  = function(name, options) {
  View.call(this, name, options);
};
MyView.prototype = Object.create(View.prototype);
MyView.prototype.lookup = function(path) {
  // `path` contains the template name to look up, so here you can perform
  // your customer-specific lookups and change `path` so that it points to
  // the correct file for the customer...
  ...

  // when done, just call the original lookup method.
  return View.prototype.lookup.call(this, path);
};
app.set('view', MyView);
```

Comment: it seems quite straightfoward and easy to implement. I'll think on it, althrought I guess middleware would be a cleaner solution.

Comment: @balanza if I can prevent monkeypatching, I usually do :)

Comment: i didn' understand if you agree with me or not (about middleware as a cleaner solution)  ;)

Comment: @balanza I don't think it's possible to do with *just* middleware and *no* monkeypatching.

Comment: I let you know soon ;)